# commands to upload sql file to database

Tags: command-line, database, sql

There is a database file in this path : /var/www/db.sql in server.

Our database size is about 800mb.

we have to upload this sql file to the database : "age"

**username : root,
password : pass,
database password : dbpass**

i am trying this command . but its not working.

```
mysql -u root -ppass age db.sql
```

i followed this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483087/importing-large-sql-file-to-mysql-via-command-line

please give the correct command

Comment: According to the link that you supply, there should be no space between "-p" and "pass".  Did you try that?

Comment: i tried that, no luck....

Comment: is i am missing in file path , i am simply putting name of sql file with out giving path

Comment: Check with the `http://dba.stackexchange.com/` community if you can.

Comment: @brendan please check : http://prntscr.com/9mo6h3

Comment: As far as i know that should work, can you tell us if you got any error messages? Define "its not working' please

Comment: its working, someone post an answer.

Comment: "Someone post an answer"? How can anybody post an answer? What do you mean by "its working"? Did you fix it? Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @DavidPostill sorry for my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using server password but i should give database password, once i gave database password, i got it.